# Is it possible to play external url song in soundcloud player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, audio-streaming

In my website user can choose song from soundcloud OR to upload his own.

so to use one player...
I need the soundcloud player to play song from my site or from soundcloud.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

[Assumption that you want to upload and play your .mp3 from SC]

Yea it is possible.

If it is from sound cloud you will play.

If it is from upload, you will upload on sound cloud and you will play that particular uploaded .mp3 or what extension you accept.

Here is the javascript official soundcloud sdk : https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript

Here is a extracurricular ruby example, but you can inspire from: 
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby

Another approach is to stream that file, but i didn't implement something like that.

Embedded example:

```
  SC.oEmbed("http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood", {auto_play: true}, function(oembed){
    console.log("oEmbed response: ", oembed);
  });
```

And you can read more here : https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

Comment: The is not what he is asking for. I beleive he wants to load a full url ending as .mp3 (example) into soundcloud player. Personally I think it is not possible.

Comment: I don't see the logic in playing just in a SC player and not in html5 one. I read again the question and i think you're right with the assumption of what he want to achieve. I think it is not possible too. It will be a business issue probably.

Comment: Hi Raz, definitely agreed with your comment. Question to the OP, why do you want to use the SC player?